# ffmpeg overlay last frame remaining in video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay

Have an issue where an overlay video has it's last frame remaining in the output video until the full video is complete.  The full video is 10 seconds and the overlay video is 5 seconds.  The overlay starts at the beginning of the video.

Example:

- `myoverlay.mov` is 5 seconds
- `myvideo.mp4` is 10 seconds

Final video (`outputvideo.mp4`) shows the last frame of `myoverlay.mov` "stuck" in the video for the remaining 5 seconds.

Desired: when the overlay is finished, should just go away and the remainder of the 5 seconds of the video continue without seeing anything from the overlay.

Command used:

```
ffmpeg -y -i myvideo.mp4 -r 30 -itsoffset 00:00:00.000 -i myoverlay.mov \
-filter_complex [1:v]scale=640:360[ovrl], [0:v][ovrl]overlay=0:0[outv]; \
[0:a][1:a]amix[outa] -map [outv] -map [outa] -c:v libx264 -vcodec mpeg4 \
-r 30 -strict experimental -b:v 1500000 outputvideo.mp4
```

Full output:

```
ffmpeg version N-70223-g7296716 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 19.100 / 54. 19.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 23.105 / 56. 23.105
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.101 /  5. 11.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'basevideo.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2015-07-13 21:32:46
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
  Duration: 00:00:45.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2436 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2234 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-07-13 21:32:46
      handler_name    : DataHandler
      encoder         : mpeg4
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 199 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-07-13 21:32:46
      handler_name    : DataHandler
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.1 : mono Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'overlayvideo.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2015-03-29 22:27:01
  Duration: 00:00:08.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 85613 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: png (png  / 0x20676E70), rgba, 640x360 [SAR 2834:2834 DAR 16:9], 84889 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-03-29 22:27:01
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : PNG
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 705 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-03-29 22:27:01
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #1:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-03-29 22:27:39
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Output #0, mp4, to 'finalvideo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt
    encoder         : Lavf56.23.105
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 ( [0][0][0] / 0x0020), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 1500 kb/s, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.26.100 mpeg4
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.26.100 libvo_aacenc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (mpeg4) -> overlay:main
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> amix:input0
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> scale
  Stream #1:1 (pcm_s16le) -> amix:input1
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (mpeg4)
  amix -> Stream #0:1 (libvo_aacenc)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1351 fps=108 q=24.8 Lsize=   15213kB time=00:00:45.10 bitrate=2762.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
video:14467kB audio:705kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.261860%
```

Comment: You should show the complete console output from your command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the fix.  Needed to use **overlay=eof_action=pass** instead of **overlay=0:0**

Updated command, which works:

```
ffmpeg -y -i myvideo.mp4 -r 30 -itsoffset 00:00:00.000 -i myoverlay.mov -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=640:360[ovrl], [0:v][ovrl]overlay=eof_action=pass[outv];[0:a][1:a]amix[outa]" -map [outv] -map [outa] -c:v libx264 -vcodec mpeg4 -r 30 -strict experimental -b:v 1500000 outputvideo.mp4
```